# Sitecore JSS getting build error VUE.JS Sample app

Tags: jss, npm

I am getting following error when trying to run `jss build` on sample `Vue JS` app.

```
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
 ERROR  Error: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency
Error: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency
    at addDependency (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:800:12)
    at iterationOfArrayCallback (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:208:3)
    at addDependenciesBlock (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:816:5)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:827:4)
    at afterBuild (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:954:15)
    at D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:998:11
    at callback (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:734:5)
    at D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:782:12
    at handleParseResult (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:478:12)
    at D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:500:6
    at D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:186:6
    at context.callback (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at D:\projects\racq-forms\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:199:12
    at D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:343:11
    at D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:678:31
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
node:events:504
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn vue-cli-service build ENOENT
    at notFoundError (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\Projects\racq-forms\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn vue-cli-service build',
  path: 'vue-cli-service build',
  spawnargs: []
```

The current versions:

Node: `v16.14.2`

Npm: `6.14.16`

JSS-CLI version: `15.0.2`

Jss app created using `jss create racq-forms vue --branch release/15.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin `mini-css-extract-plugin` using the below command.

```
npm i mini-css-extract-plugin@0.8.0

npm install --save-dev mini-css-extract-plugin@0.8.0
```